# Mainframe Sort - Getting count based on field

Tags: mainframe, syncsort

My requirement is to get the count based on the field.

For example:

```
AAA 1234  
AAA 111  
...  
AAA 112  
BBB 123  
BBB 123  
...  
BBB 333  
CCC 333
```

Output should be:

```
AAA 2000  
BBB 300  
CCC 1
```

I am using the Sort card:

```
SORT FIELDS=(1,3,CH,A)                                  
OUTFIL REMOVECC,NODETAIL,                                
  SECTIONS=(1,3,TRAILER3=(1,3,X,COUNT=(M10,LENGTH=10)))
```

But I need the count to be left justified. Currently the count is displaying with leading spaces.

How can I make these count results left justified?

Comment: You show your data to be in sequence, do you really need the SORT statement, why not OPTION COPY or SORT FIELDS=COPY? No, there is not an "edit mask" which left-justifies.  Best use of resources is to either: 1) convince the consumer of your output that really having it right-justified is not very difficult; 2) have a second SORT step which processes your three-record output and use INREC BUILD with JFY with SHIFT=LEFT. The alternative is to do the shifting on each record, which is a waste of resources.

Comment: The reason i need the count to write in this format is because i have to compare this file with other file which will have the count without leading spaces. May be i will include another sort to justify it as you mentioned. Thanks for the help!